# tangent of a square root function

Tags: trigonometry

I'm asked to solve for x:  $\tan (\sqrt{2x+3}) =3$

I put my calculator in radian mode, then took inverse tan of $3 = 1.25$ (approx).

Squaring both sides, I then get $2x+3=1.56$, so $x=-0.72$.

Two questions, (a) does squaring both sides create possible non-answers?  (b) Since tangent is cyclical, should my answer be $x=-0.72 + 2\pi n$?

Comment: B) actually the period of tan is $\pi$ and you should work it right from where you do the inverse tan i.e.  -  $\sqrt{2x+3} = 1.25 +n\pi$

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh, ok...thanks. I just meant the *argument* of tangent, didn't read anything else. Erasing comment to avoid confusion

Comment: Yes, I see this now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the period of the tangent function is $\pi$. Therefore, if $t=\tan(\theta)$, then $t=\tan(\theta +n\pi)$ for all integer values of $n$ and $\theta = \arctan(t)-n\pi$ for all integer values of $n$.

However, if the values of $\theta$ are restricted, say to non-negative real numbers, then the permissible values of $n$ will be restricted accordingly.

For the problem of interest, we have

$$\tan(\sqrt{2x+3})=3 \tag 1$$

From $(1)$, we find that $\sqrt{2x+3}=\arctan(3)+n\pi$ for $n\ge 0$, where the arctangent function is taken on the principle branch for which $|\arctan(x)|<\pi/2$.  Note that since $\sqrt{x+3}\ge 0$, the permissible values of $n$ are indeed the non-negative integers.

Next, we solve for $x$ to find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=\frac12\left(\left(\arctan(3)+n\pi\right)^2-3\right)}$$

for all $n\ge 0$. There are no spurious solutions introduced upon solving for $x$ here.

Note that the values of $x$ are *not* periodic since the term $n\pi$ appears inside the squaring operator.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, that is important to note.  I've edited as per your suggestion.  Thank you for the suggestion. -Mark